# How to change data due to selected value in select Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some chart displayed in my UI. And I have to change this chart by changing select, ie by default, my chart display some data by the past year when user select "Month" chart should show data by past month

```
    <div class="graph">
      <p>Select {{ selected }}</p>
         <form>
           <select class="select" v-model="selected">
             <option value="year">Year</option>
               <option value="month">Month</option>
                 <option value="week">Week</option>
           </select>
         </form>
   <canvas id="mix" count="2"></canvas>
   <chartjs-line target="mix"></chartjs-line>
   <chartjs-bar :labels="mylabels" :datasets="mydatasets" target="mix"></chartjs-bar>
   </div>
export default { 
  data(){
   return{
     mydatasets:[{
                    responsive:true,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    data: [20, 50, 20, 41, 26, 15, 20, 10, 29, 5, 33, 55] // this data should be changed due to selected value
                }]
         }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I have to show some data due to the selected value in the select option

    <form>
       <select class="select" @change="changeHandler" v-model="selected"> // change listener
         <option v-bind:key="item" v-for="item in selectArr">{{item}}</option>
       </select>
    </form>
   export default {
      data(){
         selected: 'Year',
         selectArr: ['Year', 'Month', 'Week']
      }
   },
      methods:{
      changeHandler(){
         let selected = this.selected;
         if (selected === 'Month'){
            this.dataChart = [2, 12, 8, 22, 31, 6, 10, 32, 5, 36, 21, 21];
         } else if (selected === 'Week') {
            this.dataChart = [8, 2, 18, 3, 13, 32, 10, 8, 12, 34, 21, 12];
         } else if (selected === 'Year') {
            this.dataChart = [44, 49, 48, 49, 55, 47, 43, 55, 53, 43, 44, 51];
          }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the change of the "selected" by the **watch** property...

```
<script>
export default { 
  data(){
    return{
      mydatasets:[{
        responsive:true,
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [20, 50, 20, 41, 26, 15, 20, 10, 29, 5, 33, 55] // this data should be changed due to selected value
      }]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selected: {
      immediate: true,
      handler: function (newValue) {
        switch (newValue) {
          case "Year":
            // this.mydatasets[0].data = somthing
            break;
          case "Month":
            // this.mydatasets[0].data = somthing
            break;
          case "Day":
            // this.mydatasets[0].data = somthing
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do that using php switch case, javascript nor ajax. i will give some example using php.

```
<?php
    $page = null;
    if(isset($_POST['page'])){
        $page = $_POST['page'];
    }
    switch($page){
        case 'page3': include_once('/path/to/some.php'); break;
        case 'page2': include_once('/path/to/some.php'); break;
        case 'page1': include_once('/path/to/some.php'); break;
        default: include_once('/path/to/default.php'); break;
    }
    ?>

<form action="" method="post">
                <select name="page" onchange="window.location=this.value"">
                    <option value="page1"<?php if($page == "page1"){ echo " selected"; }?>>Year</option>
                    <option value="page2"<?php if($page == "page2"){ echo " selected"; }?>>Month</option>
                    <option value="page3"<?php if($page == "page3"){ echo " selected"; }?>>Week</option>
                </select>
</form>
```

Its depens on option clicked.So when you click on Year, the $page get the data -> page1, then open the some.php file to showing your chart year.